# Running Capybara Specs only works one time; after, problems with factories

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I am currently having problems running capybara specs. The first time I run them they work as intended and pass. Every time after that, I get the following error:

`Validation failed: Name has already been taken`

Here is my sign_in_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe 'Sign in and client creation page' do
        let!(:team_all) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_all) }
        let!(:development) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_development, parent: team_all) }
        let!(:unassigned) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_unassigned, parent: development) }
        let!(:product_feed) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_product_feed, parent: development) }
        it 'creates a new client' do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, team: team_all)
            login_as(user, :scope => :user)
            visit ('/clients/new')
            fill_in 'client_name', with: 'Capybara'
            find('#new_client > input.button.bottom').click
            expect(page).to have_content('Add Source')
        end
    end
```

successful_source_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Successful source' do
    let!(:team_all) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_all) }
    let!(:development) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_development, parent: team_all) }
    let!(:unassigned) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_unassigned, parent: development) }
    let!(:product_feed) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_product_feed, parent: development) }
    login_user
    it 'is created' do 
        fill_in 'origin_name', with: 'Feed'
        find('#origin_feed_option_attributes_primary').click
        fill_in 'origin_source', with: 'example_url'
        find('#origin_remove_html').click
        find('#new_origin > div > div > div > input:nth-child(3)').click
        find('#new_origin > div > div > div > a').click
        expect(page).to have_content('Feed')
 end
end
```

source_error_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Source creation' do
    let!(:team_all) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_all) }
    let!(:development) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_development, parent: team_all) }
    let!(:unassigned) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_unassigned, parent: development) }
    let!(:product_feed) { FactoryGirl.create(:team_product_feed, parent: development) }
    login_user
    it 'creates bad source' do
        fill_in 'origin_name', with: 'Rules'
        find('#origin_feed_option_attributes_primary').click
        fill_in 'origin_source', with: 'example_url'
        find('#origin_remove_html').click
        find('#new_origin > div > div > div > input:nth-child(3)').click
        expect(page).to have_selector('body > div.off-canvas-wrap.full-width > div > section > section > div > div.flash-wrapper-wrapper > div > div > div')
    end
end
```

Relevant factories

```
factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@.com" }
    password 'p@ssw0rd'
  end

  factory :team, class: Teams::ProductFeed do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Team #{n}" }
  end

  factory :team_all, class: Teams::All do
    name 'All'
  end

  factory :team_development, class: Teams::Development do
    name 'Development'
  end

  factory :team_unassigned, class: Teams::Unassigned do
    name 'Unassigned'
  end

  factory :team_product_feed, class: Teams::ProductFeed do
    name 'Product Feed'
  end
```

What can I do to prevent issues with factories in the future? If parts of the rails_helper and spec_helper are needed, let me know.

Comment: You're not cleaning up your test database. How you do that depends on which version of Rails you're using, so what version of Rails are you using? Also `login_user` should be either inside the `it` block or in a `before` block (unless your `login_user` method actually registers a before block like `let' does)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I am using Rails 4.2.7.1, and the login_user method does contain a before block.

Comment: As an aside -- the selectors you're using in calls like `find('#new_origin > div > div > div > input:nth-child(3)').click` and `expect(page).to have_selector('body > div.off-canvas-wrap.full-width > div > section > section > div > div.flash-wrapper-wrapper > div > div > div')` are way too specific and will lead to very brittle tests.  You'd be much better off making those less specific by using the :text filter, or not worrying about the immediate child relationships, etc. - like `expect(page).to have_selector('div.flash-wrapper-wrapper', text: 'some message')`, etc

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thank you for the tip, I am always looking for ways to improve the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Rails < 5.1 you can't use transactional testing when testing with Capybara using any driver other than rack_test.  Because of that you need to use `database_cleaner` to manage the cleaning of the DB between tests. Add the database_cleaner gem to your project and then use the configuration shown for Capybara on the database_cleaner repo - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example.

You'll also need to ensure you comment out any other mentions of `config.use_transactional_fixtures` in your spec_helper/rails_helper